# CS-Cart + Barba.js?

Tags: javascript, cs-cart

Использую в своих проектах barba.js для переходов между страницами без перезагрузки. С CS-Cart первый опыт.
Проблема в том, что необходимо использовать скрипты данной платформы для работы интернет-магазина (добавление товара в корзину, избранное, сравнение, оформление заказа).

Каждый файл платформы подключается отдельно, все они лежат в контейнере barba.js и при переходах между страницами динамически меняются, но не инициализируются.
Видел лишь одно решение с запуском встроенных скриптов - функция eval.

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container) {
var js = container.querySelector("script");
if(js != null){
    eval(js.innerHTML);
}
```

Довольно опасное решение, которое вдобавок дублирует функции, если возвращаться на страницу с такими же скриптами.
Существует ли адекватное решение данной проблемы?